# In gensim LDA, Is there a way to construct a document wise measure of how well a topic fits it

Tags: gensim, lda

For example, if Topic A has the following distribution: word A: 0.6, word B: 0.3, word C: 0.1. And a document has been classified as Topic A based on the fact that it has word C in it. It has no other word (neither from topic A nor any other topic). Is there any metric that tells you that even though it has been assigned topic A, it is a weak assignment

Answer (score 0):

So what you are missing here is that in LDA, every single word has a probability of appearing in every single topic.  For words that do not belong in a topic, that probability is very low.  Essentially what is happening behind the scenes in LDA when documents are assigned a topic is that the probability of each word for each topic in the document is added up, and the document is assigned a topic based on the relative probability of its words being in each topic.  So, for your case, while your document is classified as Topic A because it contains word C, the probability relative to the probability of other topics will not be as high as a document that contains word A, B, and C.

So, if you want to measure the strength of the assignment of a document, you can compute the probability of a document being in each topic.  If there is a single topic that stands out amongst the rest, it is a good assignment.  As far as giving an actual threshold for a "good" or "bad" assignment, I would look at what the probability distributions over topics look like.

Comment: I think what im really looking for is document wise perplexity. Because I tried the probability thing, and like you said, got probability of word C in topic A relative to its probability in other topics. Doesnt tell me anything about Word C's relative probability in topic A.